# How to place login form to the right side of the page using angulat6 material

Tags: angular-material

I am doing project in angular6 material. I have designed login page using angular6 material, but I am not able to place that login form to the right of the page.

I have tried using margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left and right but non of them working.

Any help please..

Here is my code
app.component.html

```html
 <body>
        <div class="container">
        
        <mat-card class="example-card">
        
              <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight=5:1>
                  <mat-grid-tile>
                    <mat-card class="login">Login</mat-card>
                  </mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-grid-tile>
                      <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput placeholder="name">
                          <span matSuffix><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon></span>
    
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </mat-grid-tile>
    
                      <mat-grid-tile>
                          <mat-form-field>
                              <input matInput placeholder="password">
                          <span matSuffix><mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon></span>
    
                            </mat-form-field>
                          </mat-grid-tile>
                          <mat-grid-tile>
                              <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Submit</button>
                          </mat-grid-tile>
            
                
                </mat-grid-list>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </body>
```

app.component.css

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("/assets/pencil4.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        /* background-attachment: fixed; */
    
      }  
       */
    
    mat-card{ 
        display: flex;
        height:41% ;
        background-color: gray;
      }  
        
      
     .login{
        width:90%;
        height:30% ;
        background-color: #FFDE03;
        font-weight: 800;
        border-radius: 5px;
    } 
    
     mat-form-field{
        width:90%;
    }
    
    
    mat-grid-tile{
        width:400px;
    }
    
    .example-card {
        max-width: 300px;
      }
```

[image]

If `magin-top:800px,` 
[image]

If I use padding-top:300px;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS to example-card.
use margin-left and margin-top for align to right place.

```html
 .example-card {
        max-width: 300px;
        margin-left: 800px;
        margin-top:100px;
      }
```

if margin-top not works. try padding-top

see my example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfadvh

Comment: Thank you for your answer, margin-left working for form. But margin-top not working.

Comment: try padding-top then. both works for me. i have attached my code example.. go through it. check you did it right

Comment: If I give margin-top as 800px, It will come down along with the background image.

Comment: same with padding-top?

Comment: I have attached screenshots of results what I am getting after using margin-top and padding-top, please check the same.

Comment: try adding padding-top to container tag

Comment: On including box-sizing:border-box and position:absolute solved my problem.